# How to find which header is including another header in the include tree?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

In the [D3D12HelloWindow project](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloWindow) from Microsoft DirectX samples there is a reference to `IID_PPV_ARGS`. When I navigate with F12 in VS2017 enterprise, I reach `combaseapi.h`, but the output from the compiler with `/showincludes` does not quote it at all.

In the end, the project compiles and run correctly, but I cannot know which header is including directly or undirectly `combaseapi.h` ?

How can I find which header is using `combaseapi.h` ?

**The goal/problem is to understand a certain implementation** (a certain DirectX 12 aspect) so I can use it to enrich my own (in that case a DirectX 12 WPF asset).

Comment: yes, what is the problem, when the project compiles and runs?

Comment: @user463035818 the problem is not to make the sample run, but to understand its implementation. Reading and understanding code is an important part of engineering.

Answer (score 1):

I created very small example on my own. It doesn't work but compiling successfully:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Objbase.h"
#include "Unknwn.h"
#include "Propsys.h"

int main()
{
    IPropertyStore *pPropertyStore;

    CoCreateInstance(IID_IUnknown, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropertyStore));

    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2017, I see `combaseapi.h` included through `Objbase.h` header:

```
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\Objbase.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared\winapifamily.h
1>Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared\winpackagefamily.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared\rpc.h
...
1>Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\ole2.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared\pshpack8.h
1>Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\objbase.h
1>Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared\pshpack8.h
1>Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\combaseapi.h
...
```

Above compiler Output should be read in following way. If the line below has more indent it means that header in above line is including header from below line. I am including `#include "Objbase.h"` and in my .cpp file and going through increasing indentation I see `combaseapi.h` (last line in attached part of Output). From this I know that `Objbase.h` through 5 headers through his way is including `combaseapi.h`.

I am using Windows 10.

I don't see any remarks in [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330727(v=vs.85).aspx)

Maybe try to check debugger Output again?

Comment: OK, I'm trying to know through which .h I'm reaching combaseapi.h. Isn't through the /showincludes output ?

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'Isn't through the /showincludes output ?'   /showincludes option just list headers, their order and which one is included by which (indentation).

Comment: I didn't see combaseapi.h in the  /showincludes output. How did you find that Objbase.h was including combaseapi.h ?

Comment: @Soleil I have updated my answer. Is it more clear now?